# Send FormData + js variable by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, variables

I have this Ajax to send multiple images:

```
$('#btn').on("click", function () {
        var formData = new FormData($("#form1")[0]);
        var path = "php/upload/adm_prodpictures.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: path,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (stuff) {
                $("#resp").html(stuff);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I have to process this images in the php-side and insert them in a mysql db. So to insert in the proper way, I have to send a javascript variable. How can I append this variable to the 'bundle' that is sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To append param just use `append()` method:

```
formData.append("param", "value");
```

Comment: I've just found the solution but thanks anyway. This is exactly what I did :)

Answer (score 3):

Solved. I add:

formData.append('ipid',id);

So finally my ajax is:

```
$('#btn').on("click", function () {
        var formData = new FormData($("#form1")[0]);
        formData.append('ipid',id); //id is the variable that has the data that I need
        var path = "php/upload/adm_prodpictures.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: path,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (stuff) {
                $("#resp").html(stuff);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And in the php-side I catch it:

```
$pid = ($_POST['ipid']);
```